# Drools for Multi-Client Web Application feasible?

Tags: drools, business-rules, rule-engine

I am working on a multi-client web-based application that analyses sensor data and shall invoke actions based on this data with a rule engine. 
Every client of this application has a set of environmental sensors (10s - 100s) and a set of rules to be evaluated every time the sensor values change (the sensor values are copied into a database).
A basic set of rules will often be reused by different clients but the rules are individually parameterized (e.g. time dependant) for each client and every client has a different amount of sensors and rules, which can be configured individually. Some rules might even be specific to single clients.

I believe that drools might be a good choice for such an implementation - using drools guvnor to manage the rules for each client. Every client would have his own knowledge base and rule execution session.

I wonder if such an environment would scale and if there is a benchmark or real-world example where someone has used drools for such scenario.

Most benchmarks I could find assess different rule engines by their ability to perform rules on a growing number of facts. The amount of facts in my scenario would be relatively stable (per client) and scalability would rather be limited by the amount of clients and concurrent application of many knowledge bases and sessions.

Any comment about benchmarks or rule engine comparison regarding this scalability problem is welcome. I'd also be glad to hear about real-world implementations where every client has his own rules and dataset to work on.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with benchmarks is that they will vary a lot depending on the specific rules that you write for your own domain. Most of the benchmarks are tweaked to perform better in the rule engine that is testing. If you have a session per client and you have a stable number of client you will face no problem. Once you get the initial version of your project you can fine tune the engine to improve the performance. 
The most "difficult" thing in my opinion is to get the infrastructure right, with that I mean, when to create the sessions and how to select the rules for each of the clients. Because that's part of your specific domain, you will need to code it and manage all the sessions.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Acting on sensor data is one of the examples given for "Complex Event Processing". The following [link](http://www.ijcte.org/papers/345-G907.pdf) may give a deeper insight on this subject.

[Drools Fusion](https://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-fusion.html) is also capable of CEP.